# Is the question 'explaining gravity to a six-year-old' off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I recently asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94471/28097) about explaining gravity to a 6 year old and it  made it into the "Hot Network Questions" list. It generated a lot of discussion and has some very good answers.

Recently, a moderator commented on the question, saying:

> The point of this site is not to educate people, it's to allow people to ask high quality physics questions and get high quality answers.

I'm not sure if the question is of **high quality**. Probably not. But I've seen similar questions here before:

- [Explaining to a five year old - why don't bubbles run like water](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73564/explaining-to-a-five-year-old-why-dont-bubbles-run-like-water)
- [Explaining UV radiation to a 6 year old](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76650/explaining-uv-radiation-to-a-6-year-old)
- [Explaining Newton's Laws of motion to a 6 year old](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77191/explaining-newtons-laws-of-motion-to-a-6-year-old)
- [How do you explain spinning tops to a nine year old?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/how-do-you-explain-spinning-tops-to-a-nine-year-old)

These are my questions:

- Is the question off-topic? If so, why? I'd like some constructive feedback on this - I think it will help me ask better questions in the future.
- Is there any way I can improve the question without invalidating all the current answers?

Comment: I would point out that the fact that similar questions have been asked in the past (and are not closed) does _suggest_ that your question may be on topic, but it's not a 100% guarantee, and in particular it does not _justify_ it. (That is, "these other questions were on topic therefore mine is on topic" is not a valid argument.)

Comment: See also [this question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5409/is-it-part-of-this-sites-charter-to-dispel-ignorance-and-raise-awareness-of-sci) on the purpose of the site.

Comment: @DavidZ: "these other questions were on topic therefore mine is on topic" - I didn't say that. I was just saying I had seen many similar questions - and someone said in the question comments that my question was off-topic. This question asks for clarification: "Is my question off-topic? If so, why?". Can you please answer that? :)

Comment: Yep, I was just making a preemptive statement because somebody tries to make that argument whenever the topicality of a question is questioned. (In many cases, anyway.)

Comment: Still, you haven't answered my question :)

Comment: I think dmckee covered it.

Comment: I would advise you to ask the question you asked here http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94471/  here http://parenting.stackexchange.com/ many questions have been asked on this site  http://parenting.stackexchange.com/search?q=6+year

Answer (score 11):

I don't speak for the other moderators, but my concern with this question and the other like it is that very often the answers that such questions attract are not about physics.

In this particular case that are at least a half a dozen answers that are frankly terrible that have received lots of upvotes. "Explanations" in terms of other forces might shut the kid up, but they are ***bad physics***, and on a site about physics that makes them ***bad answers***. Yet, because of the popularity of the question they are voted up, which makes our community look unprofessional.

Brandon's this point almost from the very beginning.

> While great, this question is off topic for Physics.SE. It isn't about physics, it's about education and childhood cognition with a few physics metaphors sprinkled in. A large portion of any answer to this question could also answer "How do you explain  to a 6 year old?" which makes this question about education. The rest of the answer is about simple gravity / falling / symmetry metaphors which makes this question too broad. – Brandon Enright Jan 20 at 19:55

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you also address the second question?

Comment: I don't know that there is anything to do to "fix" it, because the fault does not really lie with the questions but with the rush of users not used to our site and whose interest is not primarily about *physics*. Your question is a victim of it's own success.

Comment: I would add that the writers of several of those bad, highly-upvoted answers have no other reputation on this site.

Comment: @ColinMcFaul  You are wrong. Would you show some statistical data about your argument.