# Not notified of new edits on meta.physics.SE

Tags: support, notifications

I recently asked [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5430/is-this-question-off-topic) on meta.physics.stackexchange.com, and one hour later, the question was [edited](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5430/revisions), but I wasn't notified of the edit.

On other sites, I'm notified when an edit is made to any of my questions / answers. But on meta.physics.SE, I'm not. Why is this?

Comment: @rene: Of course I did. In [Unicorn dollars](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OVe8N.jpg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe this is a bug, but rather it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

As the edit notification system is currently designed, users are not notified when a minor edit is made to one of their own posts.  [The exact criteria are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have/135411#comment378020_135411):

> a non-trivial edit is one which changes at least 10 characters (this is using a diff algorithm, so it's not a simple add/delete; and is naturally a little fuzzy). For the "technical" sites (where code highlighting is enabled) changes to code of at least 2 characters are considered non-trivial.

According to this, changes to tags are considered trivial and will not generate a notification.

Comment: @Shog any specific reason you migrated this one.  Seems like it would be a good reference on MSO.

Comment: Thanks, @psubsee. This was exactly it. I found out 3 minutes after asking the question and was going to self-answer but then I wasn't sure of the exact criteria and was unable to test this myself.

Comment: @Shog: This isn't a meta.physics.se-specific issue and applies to all the sites, AFAIK. So wouldn't it make sense for this to exist on MSO than here so other people could find it easily? Maybe the question can be edited to remove the physics.se specificness so it would be more general. I don't know, it's just a thought.

Comment: @AmalMurali actually I wasn't sure of the exact criteria either, but I knew retag only edits didn't notify and small edits didn't notify either.  The exact criteria were edited in by Shog prior to the post getting migrated, so that's his work.

Comment: Given the question was written as a "why do I get notified elsewhere but not here", I think it's sufficiently related to the site to be here. Edit notifications are already fairly well-documented on MSO, but not mentioned here at all, and I'd like folks to feel comfortable asking support questions on their home meta.

Comment: @Shog9 sounds good... the criteria and reasons for lack of edit notification was not easy to find on MSO, which is why I thought it might work there, but that's a good point as well.  Thanks